# Saving to a file in c

Tags: c, file, while-loop, structure, doubly-linked-list

I have a code which saves student numbers (stdnum) that located in a doubly linked list inside another doubly linked list into a file. I noticed that sometimes, it prints "(null)" and extra blank spaces. How do I avoid these? Here's my code:

```
typedef struct frn{ //structure for friend
char stdnum[20];
struct frn *next;
struct frn *prev;
}friend;

typedef struct std{ //structure for student
char stdnum[20];
char name[20];
char course[10];
struct frn *friendh; 
struct frn *friendt;
struct std *next;
struct std *prev;
}student;



FILE *fp1;
student *y = h->next;
friend *y1;
fp1 = fopen("friends.txt", "w");
    if(y != t){
        while(y != t){
            y1 = y->friendh;
            while(y1 != NULL){ 
                fprintf(fp1, "%s\n", y1->prev->stdnum);
                y1 = y1->next;
            }
            y = y->next;
        }
    }
fclose(fp1);
```

Comment: depends on what you have got inside those linked lists.

Comment: the linked list is fine, i have other fuctions which views the list and it only has valid characters inside of them. Oh, and also, each list has a dummy node. :)

Comment: Is it possible that `stdnum` is empty for some sections of linked list?

Comment: yes. for the first and last nodes, because they served as dummy nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your comments, here is why its printing NULL:

```
fprintf(fp1, "%s\n", y1->prev->stdnum)
```

what happens when you are on the very first node of your linked list (y1)( first time you enter that inner while )? When you do   **y1->prev->stdnum** you are accessing random memory Or if you have initialised your linked list to NULL values for empty values. That is what gets printed.

Then straight after printing that `null` you do `y1 = y1->next`. which takes you to the 2nd node of your linked list.

Now once again when you do :

```
fprintf(fp1, "%s\n", y1->prev->stdnum)
```

now you are printing the 'stdnum' value of the first node, which you mentioned in the comments is empty. So `fprintf` prints out a empty space.

Can you verify that the `null` and `blank space` occur right next to each other?

You can fix it like this:

```
typedef struct frn{ //structure for friend
    char stdnum[20];
    struct frn *next = NULL;
    struct frn *prev = NULL;
}friend;

fp1 = fopen("friends.txt", "w"); // I would highly recommend, you put an error check here to verify if the file opened or not 
if(y != t){
    while(y != t){
        y1 = y->friendh;
        while(y1 != NULL){ 
            if(y1->prev==NULL){
               y1 = y1->next;
            }else{
            fprintf(fp1, "%s\n", y1->prev->stdnum);
            y1 = y1->next;
            }
        }
        y = y->next;
    }
}
fclose(fp1);
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to note:

- You shouldn't use the name "friend", since it's a keyword in C++
- Check if you could open the file
- The first if (if(y != t)) is unnecessary (already coverred by the while-loop
- What is "t"? Is it a special student number?
- You are printing a string (%s), not a number (%d). Are you saving the student numbers as strings?
- Please show us the structure of the students. It's hard to answer your question without knowing how you build your list

Comment: *i'll try to use friends.txt instead
*yep, i checked and could open the file.
*oh. i'll remove it since it's not necessary.
*t is the tail of the first doubly-linked list
*im printing a string :)
*ive added my structure for students. hope it can help.